# MySQL refinement of query

Tags: mysql, search

I'm uing the following query to give me a set of the last 20 matches for a team. I want to find their goals scored in the last 20 matches and order the results by (goals scored, date):

```
SELECT * FROM (
     SELECT *, `against` AS `goalsF` , `for` AS `goalsA`
     FROM `matches` , `teams` , `outcomes`
     WHERE(
     `home_team_id`=7 AND `matches`.away_team_id = `teams`.team_id
     OR 
     `away_team_id`=7 AND `matches`.home_team_id = `teams`.team_id
     )
     AND `matches`.score_id = `outcomes`.outcome_id
     ORDER BY `date` DESC
     LIMIT 0 , 20
     ) res
ORDER BY `goalsF`
```

The problem is that:

- if the team we're looking up is the home team, we need to count "goalsfor".
- if the team ins the away team we need to count "goalsagainst" to find their for goals.

So what I need to be able to do is something like:

```
if (`home_team_id`=7 AND `matches`.away_team_id = `teams`.team_id) 
 SELECT *, `for` AS `goalsF` , `against` AS `goalsA`


if (`away_team_id`=7 AND `matches`.home_team_id = `teams`.team_id) 
 SELECT *, `against` AS `goalsF` , `for` AS `goalsA`
```

But, this must be peformed on the sub-set or results. I'm not sure if this is even possible, but it is beyond my knowledge of MYSQL.

Any help would be hugely appreciated.

Alan.

Comment: are you familiar with http://www.sqlfiddle.com/. Can you post your table structure?

Comment: I didn't know about sqlfiddle - thanks for the heads-up

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you really need to learn ANSI standard `join` syntax, where you put the `join` conditions in an `on` clause rather than a `from` clause.  Also, aliases may a query much more readable.

The following does the logic that you want, although it does not include the team names:

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT *,
             (case when m.home_team_id = 7 then o.against end) as `goalsF` ,
             (case when m.away_team_id = 7 then o.`for` end)  as `goalsA`
      FROM `matches` m join
           `outcomes` o
           on m.score_id = o.outcome_id
      WHERE m.home_team_id = 7 or m.away_team_id = 7
      ORDER BY `date` DESC
      LIMIT 0 , 20
     ) res
ORDER BY `goalsF`
```

To get the team names, you should join twice to the `teams` table, once for the home team and once for the away team.  You can do this either in the subquery or afterwards.  It is also a good idea to explicit mention the columns you are choosing and to include a table alias on every column reference:

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT m.*, o.*,
             homet.team_name as hometeam_name, awayt.team_name as away_team_name,
             (case when m.home_team_id = 7 then o.against end) as `goalsF` ,
             (case when m.away_team_id = 7 then o.`for` end)  as `goalsA`
      FROM `matches` m join
           `outcomes` o
           on m.score_id = o.outcome_id join
           teams homet
           on homet.team_id = m.home_team_id join
           teams awayt
           on awayt.team_id = m.away_team_id
      WHERE m.home_team_id = 7 or m.away_team_id = 7
      ORDER BY `date` DESC
      LIMIT 0 , 20
     ) res 
ORDER BY `goalsF`
```

EDIT:

To get just goals for team 7, you can use:

```
             (case when m.home_team_id = 7 then o.`for`
                   when m.away_team_id = 7 then o.against
              end) as goals
```

To get goals for the other team:

```
             (case when m.home_team_id = 7 then o.against
                   when m.away_team_id = 7 then o.`for`
              end) as goals
```

EDIT II:

To get the "other" team name, the logic is similar.  Replace the team name references in the `select` with:

```
             (case when m.home_team_id = 7 then awayt.team_name
                   when m.away_team_id = 7 then homet.team_name
              end) as goals
```

Comment: Gordon, Thank you, thnak you. I have been playing with this for the best paet of a day. I am going to scrutinize every line of your query in order to follow your solution. I really appreciate your input, thanks!

Comment: SOmething isn't quite right. I am getting two new columns in my results set - GoalsF and GoalsA. Is it possible to get just GoalsF which list the goals for depending on whether the team was home or away?

Comment: I think this does it: CASE WHEN m.home_team_id =7
THEN o.`against`
ELSE o.`for`
END

Comment: @gordon-linnoff The scond query which grabs the team names returns an error: Unknown column 'homet' in 'on clause'

Comment: I think it.s missing column field after table alias

Comment: It works - bar tender let that man have any drinks he wants @gordon-linoff

Comment: If I only want to find the opposition team name (I already know one of the teams afterall) I tried to narrow down the join as follows but this eturns an error: (CASE WHEN m.home_team_id =7
     THEN JOIN teams t ON t.team_id = m.home_team_id
     WHEN m.away_team_id =7
     THEN JOIN teams t ON t.team_id = m.away_team_id
     END)